# Can I install Ubuntu Server via a USB stick?

Tags: system-installation

Can I install [Ubuntu Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Ubuntu_Server) from USB sticks?

I don't want to plug a DVD player into the server.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! You can install Ubuntu by USB.

Take a look at these questions for more help:

- [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk
  Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/q/16988/10698)
- [Installation/FromUSBStick - Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just get the right [ISO image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) file for the server installation and follow the instructions in [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick).